# Delay before gameobject set active couritine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to have a delay for 3 seconds before the game object(two panels) is activated when a button is pressed. I assigned the button on click the panelview() but I could not find how to write the couritine inside as the IEnumerator.

Can somebody help me? Thanks

Here is the part of the code I want to combine the couritine into:

```
 public void panelview()
{
   

    if (totalenergy == 0)
    {
         panel2.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    }
    if (totalenergy >= 1)
    {

    panel.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick (hopefully it compiles - I didn't check it out).

```
 public void OnButtonClick() {
    
    StartCoroutine(Delay());
    
    }



 public IEnumerator Delay()
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
                
                // PanelView(); 
                // or
                // code that you want to execute it after 3 seconds
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could also use [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) without any Coroutine:

```
public void PanelView()
{
    Invoke(nameof(ShowPanel), DELAY);
}

private void ShowPanel()
{   
    if (totalenergy == 0)
    {
         panel2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (totalenergy >= 1)
    {
        panel.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Or as a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

```
public void PanelView()
{
    StartCoroutine (ShowPanelAfterDelay(DELAY));
}

private IEnumerator ShowPanelAfterDelay(float delay)
{ 
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (delay);

    if (totalenergy == 0)
    {
         panel2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (totalenergy >= 1)
    {
        panel.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

where `DELAY` is the desired delay in seconds.

---

From a UX point of view though I'd say three seconds is pretty long for giving the user feedback after a button click ;)